# How to implement step detector in Android that keeps working in the background

Tags: java, android, sensors, accelerometer, foreground-service

I got this piece of code that counts steps using accelerometer, but it only works when the app is in the foreground:

```
SensorEventListener sel = new SensorEventListener() {
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];
    // WITHOUT GRAVITY
    double magnitude = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));
    // WITH EARTH'S GRAVITY INCLUDED
    // double magnitude = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2))) / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    double magnitudeDelta = magnitude - magnitudePrevious;
    magnitudePrevious = magnitude;

    if (magnitudeDelta > 7) { // adjust the threshold based on your device
        numSteps++;
        Log.d("DELTA:", String.valueOf(magnitudeDelta));
    }
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
}
```

};

I'd like to know how to implement this using something like a foreground service, so that it keeps running in the background and the app can still get the count from it even when it restarts. I did some reading and there are no clear answers to that one, some say that the foreground service may be killed by the system if it deems it necessary because of battery drain for example. Please advise how to best go about this implementation.

I wonder if keeping the sensor running in bothonStop() and onPause() would be feasible, or would the system kill it anyway?